# add up values from siblings using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi Guys I have been working on this script for some time and I just cant make it work well I may be missing an important argument to get it to work properly..

I need to calculate the values from inside of a  tag and add up the total to a  heres the HTML:

```
<div class="catProdAttributeItem">
    <input type="radio" id="5583116" name="752526">
    <span>Ford £19.99</span>
    <img src="http://www.breakerlink.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Ford.png">
</div>

<div class="catProdAttributeItem">
    <input type="radio" id="5971554" name="752526">
    <span>Ferrary £19.99</span>
    <img src="http://www.assettocorsa.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/logo2.png">
</div> 
<br><br>
    <span style="display:none;" class="original_price">£0.00</span>
    <div class="updated_price" id="show-price">£0.00</div>
```

And here is my Script:

```
    $('.catProdAttributeItem img').on("click", function() {
    $(this).siblings('input[type=radio]').attr('checked', true);
    var original_price = $('.original_price').text().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
    parseFloat(this.original_price);
    var warehouse_price = $(this).siblings('.catProdAttributeItem span').text().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
    warehouse_price = parseFloat(warehouse_price);
    var total_price = parseFloat(original_price) + parseFloat(warehouse_price);
    $('.updated_price').html('£' + total_price.toFixed(2));
})
```

I can only get the result of the clicked siblings, please some help is much appreciated..

I was expecting to add up the values displayed on the .updated_price when the input is selected but it will work on a wider set of inputs where you can check more inputs and you would get the result from all the inputs checked

[DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/RicardoAlves/sghvyyr0/23/)

Comment: Do you generated that code? I mean... The markup? If so, you could start by putting the values in data attributes.

Comment: what's not working and what is expected behavior?

Comment: Please check the fiddle

Comment: The fiddle has a problem because your external jQuery is loaded via http, which is blocked by the browser - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dzm1hjpp/1/

Comment: Although HTML5 is now pretty well supported on modern browsers, take note that the HTML4 specifications dictate that id's must start with a letter.

Comment: so what is the expected behavior

Comment: I just realized and updated https://jsfiddle.net/RicardoAlves/sghvyyr0/23/

Comment: can you give a case, like once you click ferrari what should be the totla.. then if you select ford what should be the total

Comment: Well I was expecting to add up the values displayed on the .updated_price when the input is selected but it will work on a wider set of inputs where you can check more inputs and you would get the result from all the inputs checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the checkbox for each car (not radio). See below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.catProdAttributeItem img').on("click", function() {
    // Make checkbox adjustment
    $(this).siblings('input:checkbox').click();
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', 'input:checkbox', calcTotal);
});

function calcTotal() {
  var total_price = 0;
  // find all .catProdAttributeItem divs
  $(document).find('.catProdAttributeItem').each(function() {
    // see if the checkbox is checked to add to the total_price
    var $checkbox = $(this).find('input:checkbox');
    if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
      var text = $(this).find('span').html();
      total_price += parseFloat(text.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''))
    }
  });
  // finally display the price
  $('.updated_price').html('£' + total_price.toFixed(2));
}
```

```css
.catProdAttributeItem {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
.updated_price {
  clear: both;
  margin: 20px 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="catProdAttributeItem">
  <input type="checkbox" id="5583116" name="752526">
  <span>Ford £19.99</span>
  <img src="http://www.breakerlink.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Ford.png">
</div>

<div class="catProdAttributeItem">
  <input type="checkbox" id="5971554" name="752526">
  <span>Ferrary £19.99</span>
  <img src="http://www.assettocorsa.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/logo2.png">
</div>
<br>
<br>

<div class="updated_price" id="show-price">£0.00</div>
```

Comment: I posted that I wanted it to be able to click on the image and the radio button would activate and sum the results on the ID container, but the problem I had with yours is that when i clicked the image I had also to click on the checkbox as well dunowhy! so I end up thinking why not to assign the function to the radio button and checkbox and create another function to make the image a radio button and also your code for some reason didn't pick up the result when checking another checkbox from another group to sum up so I created a call to add what's inside the ID container + a new value Thank

Comment: Superb! that one did it! I used a css before but it lags some browser compatibility on the grampa IE's.

 .catProdAttributeItem > input{ /* HIDE RADIO */
  visibility: hidden; /* Makes input not-clickable */
  position: absolute; /* Remove input from document flow */
}
.catProdAttributeItem > input + img{ /* IMAGE STYLES */
  cursor:pointer;
  border:2px solid transparent;
}
.catProdAttributeItem > input:checked + img{ /* (RADIO CHECKED) IMAGE STYLES */
  border:2px solid #f00;
}

Comment: Thanks Bro! I have done it! you helped me real good, how long do you know Javascript?, I started a web course but its not easy to remember all these classes and combine all this together. I go nuts sometimes ;-D

Comment: It's been few years. Now with jQuery (and no IE) everything is so easy ;o)

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of what you're trying to do, you will want to simply iterate over all `.catProdAttributeItem` elements and add the price only if the radio button is checked:

```
var warehouse_price = 0;

$('.catProdAttributeItem')
    .filter(function() {
        // only interested in checked radio boxes
        return $('input:checked', this).length > 0;
    })
    .each(function() {
        var price = parseFloat($('span', this).text().replace(/[^\d.]/, ''));
        warehouse_price += price;
    });

$('.updated_price').html('£' + total_price.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: you got my idea but the trigger is the image once the image is clicked the radio bt gets the value of checked and the values from siblings (span) are added, your script is not returning the sum for some reason.

Comment: @Skwashy Oops, I was using the wrong selector; it should work now.

Comment: Hey Jack thanks but I still can't get it to work on the console it didn't grab the results but its blocking me now from using the same radio button, very weird.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a combination of Sigismundus answer + A bit of twicks to be able to grab the results from both either the radio buttons and check boxes the img click didn't work quite well, but now if added a new function to get the images as radio buttons it would work.

```
var priceSelect = parseFloat(document.getElementById("totalprice").value);
$('.catProdAttributeItem input[type=radio], .catProdAttributeItem input[type=checkbox] ').on("click", function() {
    var total_price = 0;
    $(document).find('.catProdAttributeItem').each(function() {
      var $checkbox = $(this).find('input:radio, input:checkbox');
      if ($checkbox.is(':checked')) {
        var text = $(this).find('span').html();
        total_price += parseFloat(text.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, ''))
      }
    });
    $('#totalprice').html('£' + total_price.toFixed(2));

    document.getElementById('totalprice').value = total_price+priceSelect;
  });
```